# same unit in the direction of y-axis in two plots

Tags: matlab, equals, axes

Suppose that:

```
x=1:10;
y=x.^2;

h(1)=subplot(3,1,1:2);
plot(x,y);

h(2)=subplot(3,1,3);
plot(x,y);
```

I am wondering whether there is any way to have a same data unit in the direction of y-axis for both plots (e.g. shortening the y-axis of upper figure so that it becomes equal to the y-axis of the bottom one)?

Thank you so much in advance,
Werner

Comment: See [`linkaxes`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linkaxes.html)

Answer (score 0):

As Dev-iL has already pointed out. The sample code could be

```
x=1:10;
y=x.^2;%First Output
z=x.^1.5;%Another output

figure
h(1)=subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x,y);
grid 'on'

h(2)=subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x,z);
grid 'on'

linkaxes([h(2) h(1)],'y');
```